# How can I factor a closure out of an outer function to reuse said closure in different contexts?

Tags: javascript, function, refactoring, closures, code-reuse

### Suppose I have this bit of code that deals with event handling.

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

btn.addEventListener('click', say('hello'));
btn2.addEventListener('click', shout('yo'));

function say(word) {
    var saying = word;
    var container = document.getElementById('result1');
    return function handleEvent() {
        var text = document.createTextNode(saying);
        container.innerHTML = '';
        container.appendChild(text);
    };
}

function shout(word) {
    var saying = word.toUpperCase();
    var container = document.getElementById('result2');
    return function handleEvent() {
        var text = document.createTextNode(saying);
        container.innerHTML = '';
        container.appendChild(text);
    };
}
```

Uppon clicking on **btn1**, "hello" is displayed in **result1**.

Uppon clicking on **btn2**, "YO" is displayed in **result2**.

Now, as you may have noticed, the two *handleEvent* functions are exactly the same. What I want to achieve is something like.

```
function say(word) {
    var saying = word;
    var container = document.getElementById('result1');
    return handleEvent;
}

function shout(word) {
    var saying = word.toUpperCase();
    var container = document.getElementById('result2');
    return handleEvent;
}

function handleEvent() {
    var text = document.createTextNode(saying);
    container.innerHTML = '';
    container.appendChild(text);
}
```

But that of course will not work as the *handleEvent* function is not declared inside the *say* and *shout* functions; thus, *saying* and *container* will not be defined.

I have tried playing around with *bind()* and declare *saying* and *container* on *this* inside the *say* and *shout* functions :

```
function say(word) {
    this.saying = word;
    this.container = document.getElementById('result1');
    return handleEvent.bind(this);
}

function shout(word) {
    this.saying = word.toUpperCase();
    this.container = document.getElementById('result2');
    return handleEvent.bind(this);
}

function handleEvent() {
    var text = document.createTextNode(this.saying);
    this.container.innerHTML = '';
    this.container.appendChild(text);
}
```

But that didn't work either.

---

#### How can i factor the *handleEvent* function out of the *say* and *shout* functions?

Thank you!

[JsBin setup](https://jsbin.com/galawopixu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding should have worked if you had created new objects to be bound to, instead of using [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

```
function say(word) {
    return handleEvent.bind({
        saying: word,
        container: document.getElementById('result1')
    });
}

function shout(word) {
    return handleEvent.bind({
        saying: word.toUpperCase(),
        container: document.getElementById('result2')
    });
}
```

---

However, you still can solve this with a normal closure:

```
function say(word) {
    return makeHandleEvent(word, 'result1');
}

function shout(word) {
    return makeHandleEvent(word.toUpperCase(), 'result2');
}


function makeHandleEvent(saying, id) {
    var container = document.getElementById(id);
    return function handleEvent() {
        var text = document.createTextNode(saying);
        container.innerHTML = '';
        container.appendChild(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse a closure in a different context, because by definition in javascript a closure is an inner function which is bound to the context of its parent.

You can however extract your function body in order to reuse it in different contexts:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

btn.addEventListener('click', say('hello'));
btn2.addEventListener('click', shout('yo'));

function saySomething(context, saying) {
    var text = document.createTextNode(saying);
    container.innerHTML = '';
    container.appendChild(text);
};

function say(word) {
    var saying = word;
    var container = document.getElementById('result1');
    return function handleEvent() {
        saySomething(context, saying);
    };
}

function shout(word) {
    var saying = word.toUpperCase();
    var container = document.getElementById('result2');
    return function handleEvent() {
        saySomething(context, saying);
    };
}
```

Or if you want to use bind:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

btn.addEventListener('click', say('hello'));
btn2.addEventListener('click', shout('yo'));

function saySomething(context, saying) {
    var text = document.createTextNode(saying);
    container.innerHTML = '';
    container.appendChild(text);
};

function say(word) {
    var saying = word;
    var container = document.getElementById('result1');
    return saySomething.bind(undefined, context, saying);
}

function shout(word) {
    var saying = word.toUpperCase();
    var container = document.getElementById('result2');
    return saySomething.bind(undefined, context, saying);
}
```

Comment: I guess a small change will be required above.
You have to call saySomething(context, saying) instead of returning it as a closure. By returning it as closure the function saySomething() wont get executed at all.

Comment: The closure is returned because that's used by addEventListener as handler. You need it. Same with bind. You don't want to actually call saySomething from inside say or shout, you just want it returned and bound to their contexts.

Comment: Bind will work fine the way you have mentioned. But not the first one.
The code will return a function instaed of executing it. So it will never go inside function saySomething. I think you have overlooked it.

Comment: Bind doesn't execute that function either, it returns another one.